# alter session set store.mongo.bson.record.reader doesn't work in Drill

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache-drill

Could you please help me ?
I'm trying to do : `alter session set store.mongo.bson.record.reader= false;` in Apache Drill but the output shows that it's still set to true.
I really need to change it so that I can read the real value of _id in MongoDB

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  http://localhost:8047/options (*assuming drill is running in localhost*).

And change your property to `false` and update it.